# How to write a macro in google sheets to refresh a bigquery data connector?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros, data-connections

Trying to create a macro that refreshes a bigquery data connection.

Have tried to record a macro, starting on a different tab, clicking into the tab with the data connector and clicking refresh.

```
function Refresh2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F3').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Extract 2'), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [guide](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/02/refresh-bigquery-data-sheets.html) here, you should be able to do it.

Here is what I've got and it works flawlessly:

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function refresh() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data Sheet 1'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
};
```

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965058/wait-for-formula-to-be-completed-before-executing-script/56978670#56978670) may be interesting if you have yet another step after refreshing BigQuery source.

Comment: Does this work within google sheets also?
When I copy that code into my script it still doesn't refresh.

Comment: Updated my answer, I pasted the macro that got recorded. It seems your macro recording must have had some problem.